# XML sorting using XSLT

Tags: xml, sorting, xslt

I am new to `xslt` and want to sort below `xml` by  node

```
  <HAZARDS>
  <HAZARD>
    <ID>00000000000000000001</ID>
    <TEXT>Interior</TEXT>
    <TYPE>I</TYPE>
    <ACTIVE/>
    <COMMENTS>
      <COMMENT>
        <ID>00000000000000000011</ID>
        <VALUE>Other</VALUE>
        <ACTIVE>1</ACTIVE>
      </COMMENT>
    </COMMENTS>
    <REMEDIES>
      <REMEDY>
        <ID>00000000000000000012</ID>
        <VALUE>Other</VALUE>
        <ACTIVE>1</ACTIVE>
      </REMEDY>
    </REMEDIES>
  </HAZARD>
  <HAZARD>
    <ID>00000000000000000002</ID>
    <TEXT>Exterior</TEXT>
    <TYPE>E</TYPE>
    <ACTIVE/>
    <COMMENTS>
      <COMMENT>
        <ID>00000000000000000021</ID>
        <VALUE>Other</VALUE>
        <ACTIVE>1</ACTIVE>
      </COMMENT>
    </COMMENTS>
    <REMEDIES>
      <REMEDY>
        <ID>00000000000000000022</ID>
        <VALUE>Other</VALUE>
        <ACTIVE>1</ACTIVE>
      </REMEDY>
    </REMEDIES>
  </HAZARD>
</HAZARDS>
```

so that the the output should be:

```
  <HAZARDS>     
   <HAZARD>
      <ID>00000000000000000002</ID>
      <TEXT>Exterior</TEXT>
      <TYPE>E</TYPE>
      <ACTIVE/>
      <COMMENTS>
        <COMMENT>
          <ID>00000000000000000021</ID>
          <VALUE>Other</VALUE>
          <ACTIVE>1</ACTIVE>
        </COMMENT>
      </COMMENTS>
      <REMEDIES>
        <REMEDY>
          <ID>00000000000000000022</ID>
          <VALUE>Other</VALUE>
          <ACTIVE>1</ACTIVE>
        </REMEDY>
      </REMEDIES>
    </HAZARD>
    <HAZARD>
      <ID>00000000000000000001</ID>
      <TEXT>Interior</TEXT>
      <TYPE>I</TYPE>
      <ACTIVE/>
      <COMMENTS>
        <COMMENT>
          <ID>00000000000000000011</ID>
          <VALUE>Other</VALUE>
          <ACTIVE>1</ACTIVE>
        </COMMENT>
      </COMMENTS>
      <REMEDIES>
        <REMEDY>
          <ID>00000000000000000012</ID>
          <VALUE>Other</VALUE>
          <ACTIVE>1</ACTIVE>
        </REMEDY>
      </REMEDIES>
    </HAZARD>
    </HAZARDS>
```

I have seen a couple of posts and created below xslt , but it doesn't seem to work

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
                xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
                xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:template match="HARARDS">
        <xsl:for-each select="//HAZARD">
            <xsl:sort select="TEXT"/>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="HAZARDS"/>
    <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
        <xsl:copy>
            Heading ------- 
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Thanks so much in advance for your help.

Comment: Format your XML using: http://www.xmltoolbox.com/. Then you can indent it using control-K.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need for using `xsl:for-each` in your example.
Try this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
                xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
                xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:template match="HAZARDS">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="//HAZARD">
                <xsl:sort select="TEXT"/>
            </xsl:apply-templates>
        </xsl:copy> 
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Which will generate the following output:

```
<HAZARDS>
  <HAZARD>
    <ID>00000000000000000002</ID>
    <TEXT>Exterior</TEXT>
    <TYPE>E</TYPE>
    <ACTIVE/>
    <COMMENTS>
      <COMMENT>
        <ID>00000000000000000021</ID>
        <VALUE>Other</VALUE>
        <ACTIVE>1</ACTIVE>
      </COMMENT>
    </COMMENTS>
    <REMEDIES>
      <REMEDY>
        <ID>00000000000000000022</ID>
        <VALUE>Other</VALUE>
        <ACTIVE>1</ACTIVE>
      </REMEDY>
    </REMEDIES>
  </HAZARD>
  <HAZARD>
    <ID>00000000000000000001</ID>
    <TEXT>Interior</TEXT>
    <TYPE>I</TYPE>
    <ACTIVE/>
    <COMMENTS>
      <COMMENT>
        <ID>00000000000000000011</ID>
        <VALUE>Other</VALUE>
        <ACTIVE>1</ACTIVE>
      </COMMENT>
    </COMMENTS>
    <REMEDIES>
      <REMEDY>
        <ID>00000000000000000012</ID>
        <VALUE>Other</VALUE>
        <ACTIVE>1</ACTIVE>
      </REMEDY>
    </REMEDIES>
  </HAZARD>
</HAZARDS>
```